# My app crashes when first opened and when I sign out using android firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created an android chat app using firebase - the app works fine but when first opened, the app crashes in login page but after this the app restarts and works fine.
**Please help me with a solution because I am a beginner in this field tell me what I should change to make it work**

My logcat:
beginning of crash

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object
>   reference at
>   com.dndna.chat_rooms.views.base.BasePresenter.getCurrentUserId(BasePresenter.java:78)
>           at com.dndna.chat_rooms.views.main.MainPresenter.checkPendingNotification(MainPresenter.java:198)
>           at com.dndna.chat_rooms.views.main.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:262)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1456)
>           at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7614)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4412)

The problem seems to be in these locations

```java
public void checkPendingNotification() {
    if (getCurrentUserId() != null)
        notifyManager.checkPendingNotification(this::showBadgeAt);
}
```

and

```java
if (presenter != null) {
    presenter.checkPendingNotification();
}
```

and

```java
protected String getCurrentUserId() {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
}
```

Comment: You're calling `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();` when `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` returns `null`. The solution is to detect that `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` is null, and then do something else in your code (since the user isn't signed in yet).

Comment: thanks for your comment but can you please explain what shold i do and code snippet ?

Comment: I think your google-serives.json has some invalid keys which is telling you unauthrized...
Please get latest google-services.json file
Basicaly firebase config file

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen explained what you should do. Check that getCurrentUser() for null like you did in your other code segments.

Comment: @Rohit did not solve any thing yet still crashing at first open

Comment: wen i tryed to change from if (presenter != null) { to if (presenter == null) { its work fine in android api 23 but crashes in all other apis

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Fair enough, puf. I just deleted the comment. Thanks.